# Is there any algorithm to classify 29 category and predict in python?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, multiclass-classification

I have 29 category as target variable so which algorithm can help me to classify and predict.
Is decision tree helpful or some other multi-nominal algorithm are there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is highly dependent on the dataset you have and the characteristics of your variables. Also, you have to decide on whether you like to do supervised learning or unsupervised learning.

Read more here [Classification with multiple target variables](https://towardsdatascience.com/regression-models-with-multiple-target-variables-8baa75aacd).